# How to override dpkg-buildflags CFLAGS?

Tags: ubuntu, build, debian, dpkg

I got a package with:

```
$ apt-get source <pkg-name>
```

and now I am trying to build it with:

```
$ dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -j8
```

At the beginning of the output, there is stated:

```
dpkg-buildpackage: export CFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security
dpkg-buildpackage: export CPPFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
dpkg-buildpackage: export CXXFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security
dpkg-buildpackage: export FFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: export LDFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro
```

I would like to override these CFLAGS (also, the LDFLAGS). I have tried exporting the CFLAGS envvar, the same way we do with plain configure, at no avail. How can I override these values?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

the package you are trying to rebuild, sets (read: overrides) the *FLAGS  with hardening-specifics flags retrieved from `dpkg-buildflags`.

if you need to override those flags for your own purposes, you should tell `dpkg-buildflags` to provide the flags you want, rather than the (hardening) defaults.
looking at `man dpkg-buildflags`, you find the section about environment variables, esp. see `DEB_flag_SET` and `DEB_flag_APPEND`

so this should do the trick (fill in your own *FLAGS):

```
$ DEB_CPPFLAGS_SET="-I/foo/bar/baz" DEB_CFLAGS_SET="-g -O6" DEB_LDFLAGS_SET="-L/fruzzel/frazzel/" dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -j8 -rfakeroot
```

Comment: What if it doesn't look like dpkg-buildflags is being run? How hard is it to add that to a package? Is there an alternative command?

Comment: This answer may no longer be current.  (See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/dpkg-buildpackage.1.html#Notes)  A more recent recommendation is to edit the debian/rules script inside your the distribution you've downloaded with apt-get source and search for instances of CFLAGS/CXXFLAGS/LFLAGS.

Comment: @DaveMcMordie Recommendation by whom? But indeed some packages might ignore `DEB_CFLAGS_SET`. I'm looking at you, `exim4` on Debian 6. In which case you can do `dpkg-buildpackage -R'make -f debian/rules CFLAGS=-g3`. Or `dpkg-buildpackage -R'sh ./1.sh'`, where `1.sh`: `make -f debian/rules CFLAGS='-g3 -Og' "$@"` (if your command needs quotes). On a side note, if I were up to debugging a program, I'd go with `-g3 -Og` or just `-g3` (if `-Og` is not supported). `-g` might also suffice, but the resulting image doesn't include macro info (can't use macros in expressions).

Comment: The DEB_CFLAGS_SET variable has no effect on debian bullseye.

Comment: @GrahamLeggett i doubt it. i've just tested on bookworm/sid (bookworm is the next (upcoming) release after bullseye, and it still works. the package i tested this on uses **short-form `dh`** (pretty much the standard). of course package maintainers can do all kind of things in d/rules, and might have (accidentally) broken `DEB_*_SET` (many non-official Debian packages out there are of sub-par quality from a packaging perspective)