# Compiling CodeViz patch for GCC on 64 bit debian

Tags: c++, c, gcc, codeviz

I am trying to compile [CodeViz](http://www.csn.ul.ie/~mel/projects/codeviz/) on 64 bit Debian.  However, I am finding that the included patch for GCC causes GCC not to compile.   When I extract GCC 4.6 and compile it manually (by running

```
$ ../gcc-4.6.4/configure --prefix=/home/jeremy/gcc-codeviz --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-bootstrap
$ make
```

) it compiles without error.  However, when I apply the included patch, it fails with the error

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../libsupc++/.libs/libsupc++convenience.a(cp-demangle.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
../libsupc++/.libs/libsupc++convenience.a(cp-demangle.o): error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The patch can be seen here http://pastebin.com/djSQYe5a . It's really not that complicated, doesn't change any build options or includes, and doesn't use any advanced language features.  I really don't understand how this causes a linking error which doesn't show up in the vanilla gcc build.  Furthermore, the error itself occurs in "cp-demangle.o", which I don't think should even be touched by the patch!  My best guess is that it has something to do with the extern int cdepn_dump which is declared, or the declaration of the functions in tree.h.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: according to http://fossies.org/linux/privat/codeviz-1.0.12.tar.gz/index_ap.html the packages has the `debian/` and specifically `debian/rules` file, which can be used to compile using `dpkg-buildpackage` program without needing to do "anything"

Comment: I have tried this, as well as trying various debian patched versions of gcc.  As for the debian/rules file, it just calls a bash script which downloads vanilla gcc, applies the patch, and compiles gcc as I did above.

Comment: ok, I thought u didn't notice

Answer (score 0):

This patch can be applied to the source of Debian gcc-4.6

```
apt-get source gcc-4.6
cp gcc-4.6.2-cdepn.diff gcc-4.6-4.6.3/debian/patches
```

to rules.patch

```
nano gcc-4.6-4.6.3/debian/rules.patch

debian_patches += \
        libstdc++-pic \
        ...
        gcc-4.6.2-cdepn \
```

The main error occurs because the function **fprintf**.
[The default compiler flags includes -Wformat -Wformat-security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260409/fprintf-error-format-not-a-string-literal-and-no-format-arguments-werror-for) which is what gives this error. Disabled with **-Wformat=0 or -Wno-format-security** in CPPFLAGS or/and CFLAGS.

Also look to gcc-4.6-4.6.3/debian/patches/fix-warnings.diff for src/gcc/toplev.c and to gcc-4.6-4.6.3/debian/rules2, [dpkg-buildflags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072724/how-to-override-dpkg-buildflags-cflags)
 just for information.

```
export DEB_BUILD_MAINT_OPTIONS=hardening=-all,-format
export DEB_CFLAGS_MAINT_APPEND=-fPIC,-Wformat=0,-Wno-format-security
export DEB_CPPFLAGS_MAINT_APPEND=-fPIC,-Wformat=0,-Wno-format-security
export DEB_CXXFLAGS_MAINT_APPEND=-fPIC,-Wformat=0,-Wno-format-security
dpkg-buildflags

dpkg-buildpackage -b -d -rfakeroot -us -uc
```