# How to rebuild all Debian packages of a system with specific flag?

Tags: compilation, debian, package

I would like to rebuild/recompile all Debian packages of a machine with specific flags.

How can I do that with less command as possible?

I have found that https://debian-administration.org/article/20/Rebuilding_Debian_packages but it does not explain how to do that for all the packages installed on a system.

Comment: Similar question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184812/how-to-update-all-debian-packages-from-source-code

Comment: @kjyv that is not the same question the other one want to update all from source ... I wish to rebuild all from source + specific flag ... the idea is not to have only something up to date but build as I wish.

The evidence is also that the response is different.

Comment: Not saying your question is a duplicate, just that there might be relevant answers in that question (hence "similar"). Also for others (like me) searching for this. The other question is not about updating either btw., that's not how apt building from source works.

Comment: The answer you accepted only reinstalls binary packages. It seem likely that with debian there is no easy built in way to recompile all packages (with or without flags).
What you want to do can be done per package like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072724/how-to-override-dpkg-buildflags-cflags

Comment: That sounds to be a good idea that you adapt the response of that link to that question ... so I would vote for your answered :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a script that does something like this:

for each $pkg in `dpkg-query -W -f '${status} ${package}\n' | sed -n 's/^install ok installed //p'`:

- run apt-get source $pkg
- run apt-get build-dep $pkg
- cd $pkg-version/
- run DEB_CPPFLAGS_SET="-I/foo/bar/baz" DEB_CFLAGS_SET="-g -O3" DEB_LDFLAGS_SET="-L/fruzzel/frazzel/" dpkg-buildpackage
- install package with dpkg -i deb-file
- cd ..

This will go through all of your installed packages and generate .deb files for each of them. Probably there are some edge cases etc. that will have to be handled. You could also leave out packages that are not built from C code etc.

Info taken from these questions:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184812/how-to-update-all-debian-packages-from-source-code

[How to override dpkg-buildflags CFLAGS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072724/how-to-override-dpkg-buildflags-cflags)

Comment: Thanks for your effort!

Comment: I have heard about build-system ... do you think there is a way to do it with it??

Comment: Not sure what you mean, all of the above is part of the debian build system. There is no build-system command.

Comment: I was thinking of https://wiki.debian.org/SystemBuildTools#Intro , yes that would mean more stuff than a command line but maybe a way to do it as a all in one

Comment: well, feel free to look into any of those :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this approach:

```
dpkg --get-selections > selections
sudo dpkg --clear-selections
sudo dpkg --set-selections < selections
sudo apt-get --reinstall dselect-upgrade
```

Source:
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/force-apt-get-to-redownload-and-reinstall-dependencies-as-well-873038/

Comment: Can you write an example with specific flags on rebuild?

Comment: This does not rebuild anything